# Show progress bar when switching activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Please direct me how to show progress bar when switching between activiies.
On my second activity there are lots of calculations and coded views and it leads to expected delays in opening. But I want to show a loading progress in percentage
More details on attached screen shot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTFGZ.png)

Comment: You should understand if the "heavy" work is required to open the activity i.e. to inflate the view.  If the view can inflate without this computation then you should be doing these computations asynchronously, at which point you could show a progress bar in the target Activity.  Do you get any warnings about "skipped frames" in logcat when opening the Activity? Also looking at view stubbing - https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand

Comment: Use Fragment and navigation component with shared view model

Comment: There is no "skipped frames" in logcat while loading. The number of views and their content fully depends on calculations and are dynamic number. To my current knowledge I can't inflate them without it (or I don't know how)

Comment: Activity 2 has 50 Layouts generated by code and each of them contains around 20 Textviews. And they are created and filled with content using computation in code

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea but not the best one you could use the sharedPreference to recover the value

Comment: "I have an idea" - and the perfect time to elaborate would be in the "answer" you posted, no?